# How to remove wildcard in string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying the following...

```
$string = "*abc*"
$string = $string -replace "*",""
Write-Host $string
```

but get the following error

```
Regular expression pattern is not valid: *.
At C:\Scripts\Tests\testing.ps1:3 char:1
+ $string = $string -replace "*",""
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (*:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression
```

I've tried `-replace`, `.replace`, `.trim`, but none of them are working because they are all reading it as a regular expression. I've also tried `` "`*" ``, and it still doesn't work.

Anyone know how to make the system not to read as a regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `\` to escape it instead of the backtick.

Comment: It's confirmed this also works, however backslashes are risky since the regex for removing whitespaces are `\s`. I think the square brackets are the safer bet. I'll still mark your answer is being correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this ?

```
$string = $string.replace('*','')
```

Hope it will work !

Comment: This is the answer that avoids issues with wildcards and does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use square brackets to remove the characters.

```
$string = $string -replace '[*]', ''
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. Using the `\*` also worked, but I noticed a bug if the string involves spaces. I think your way is much better. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the system to use regex then you should not be using a regex operator like `-replace`. The string method `.Replace()` would work just as fine. You said `.Trim()` did not work either but indeed it does. Possibly and issue with your real data as supposed to your example in the question.

```
PS C:\temp> "'{0}'" -f "*abc*".replace("*","")
'abc'

PS C:\temp> "'{0}'" -f "*abc*".Trim("* ")
'abc'

PS C:\temp> "'{0}'" -f "*  abc* ".Trim("* ")
'abc'
```